# how to get second highest salary department wise if second highest salary not available then display first higest salary?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

how to find the second highest salary department wise if there is only one salary in dept then display that first highest salary.
input as

```
dept_id salary
10      500      
10      600
10      1000
20      800
20      900
20      200
30      1200
```

output

```
dept_id salary
10      600
20      800
30      1200
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `MAX()`.

Comment: can you please share the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use window functions:

```
select dept_id, salary
from (
    select
        t.*,
        row_number() over(partition by dept_id order by salary desc) rn,
        count(*) over(partition by dept_id) cnt
    from mytable t
) t
where rn = 2 or (rn = 1 and cnt = 1)
```

The subquery ranks records having the same department by decreasing salary, and counts how many employees each department has. You can then use this information to filter in the outer query.